# Twoway binding datagrid wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, two-way-binding

> I want to bind CLR property into datagrid Row How to Bind row binding in datagrid(Twoway Mode)
> [image]
> CodeBehind:

```
public partial class TechnicalPropertiesU_Var : Window
    {
        public TechnicalPropertiesU_Var()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Myclass> myclassList = new List<Myclass>();
            myclassList.Add(new Myclass() { IA = 0, IB = 0, IC = 0, ID = 0, IE = 0, IF = 0, IF = 0 });
            MyGrid.ItemsSource = myclassList;
        }
    }
```

> MyWindow Xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Value"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

> Model Class

```
public class Myclass
{
private int iA;
private int iB;
private int iC;
private int iD;
private int iE;
private int iF;
private int iG;

public int IA{get=>iA; set=>iA =value;}
public int IB{get=>iB; set=> iB =value;}
public int IC{get=>iC; set=> iC =value;}
public int ID{get=>iD; set=> iD =value;}
public int IE{get=>iE; set=> iE =value;}
public int IF{get=>iF; set=> iF =value;}
public int IG{get=>iG; set=> iG =value;}
}
```

> How to get particular column in datagrid field. please give any samples

Comment: Are they all int? Pass MyClass and a propertyinfo defines the property to bind into a row viewmodel. That works out the name of the property, exposes it's own int property to bind. The getter and setter of that property use the propertyinfo to get and set the property. Use reflection to obtain a list of propertyinfo in MyClass.

Comment: You don't need reflection or any propertyinfo here. You data structure is also wrong. If the result you are trying to get is a table with two columns (see your image) then you obviously mixed up rows and columns I guess. You data class must have two properties: `ArgumentName` and `ArgumentValue`. You must know that each item (or each instance of `MyClass` will be displayed as a row. Now, for each row create an instance of of `MyClass` and add it to the source collection. The bind the `DataGridTextColumn.Binding` property to the column's related property of the `MyClass` model.

Comment: For a two way binding, the `MyClass` must implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Comment: @BionicCode please give any sample code

Comment: To show you what exactly? How do define a class with two properties?

Answer (score 1):

If the result you are trying to get is a table with two columns (see your image) then you obviously mixed up rows and columns I guess. You data class must have two properties: `ArgumentName` and `ArgumentValue`. You must know that each item (or each instance of `MyClass`) will be displayed as a row. Now, for each row create an instance of of `MyClass` and add it to the source collection. The bind the `DataGridTextColumn.Binding` property to the column's related property of the `MyClass` model.

The following example will show the table from your image:

**MyTableClass.cs**

```
public class MyTableClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyTableClass(int argumentName, int argumentValue)
    {
        this.ArgumentName = argumentName;
        this.ArgumentValue = argumentValue;
    }

    private int argumentName;   
    private int argumentValue;

    public int ArgumentName{get=>argumentName; set{argumentName=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}}
    public int ArgumentValue{get=>argumentValue; set{argumentValue=value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**TechnicalPropertiesU_Var.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TechnicalPropertiesU_Var : Window
{
    public TechnicalPropertiesU_Var()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<MyTableClass> myTableClasses = new List<MyTableClass>();

        myTableClasses.Add(new MyTableClass() { ArgumentName = "IA", ArgumentValue = 5 });
        myTableClasses.Add(new MyTableClass() { ArgumentName = "IB", ArgumentValue = 3 });
        myTableClasses.Add(new MyTableClass() { ArgumentName = "IC", ArgumentValue = 2 });
        myTableClasses.Add(new MyTableClass() { ArgumentName = "ID", ArgumentValue = 0 });
          
        MyGrid.ItemsSource = myTableClasses;
    }
}
```

**MyWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Name" Binding="{Binding ArgumentName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Value" Binding="{Binding ArgumentValue}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

---

To address your comment:
"i dont want to bind argumentname and argument value property. i want to bind my own CLR property. because i have 250 variables."

I don't have to understand your intentions to tell you that this is a bad idea. A class shouldn't have 250 properties. Your image shows clearly that not all 250 properties have a relation, but only two have.

In your case a datum consists of a string value e.g., `"IA"` and a numeric value e.g. `5`. You should change your class to reflect this.
You should know that in common relational database design a data record is represented by a row. Each row is an object and each column of this row an attribute of this object. The `DataGrid´ is designed with the same intention: each row is an item of the` DataGrid.ItemsSource`. Each item is a separate instance. It is common to read any table e.g., a price table of products, from left to right, where each column of a row is expected to relate to a single data item e.g. product.

I highly recommend to drop your initial intention and change your data classes to reflect the relationship of your data like the example's `MyTableClass` reflects the relation of a data object (row) with two attributes (columns).

Comment: i dont want to bind argumentname and argument value property. i want to bind my own CLR property. because i have 250 variables. so i want to bind row-wise,not column wise. how to use first row as header in datagrid wpf xaml

Comment: _"i want to bind my own CLR property."_ Please explain: what is your own CLR property? In general I don't understand. You want to create multiple rows from a single item? This is not possible without some effort. You can think about changing your data structure. In a table a row represents a data set. You should clean up your data structure. `DataGrid` reflects this common practice: each item inside `ItemsSource` is rendered as a row. Your best solution is to convert your items to appropriate data structure (see my updated example) or even better replace your `Myclass` with the above version.

Comment: And I thought you gave great example.  CoderGreat obviously new and not quite grasping what you are proposing.  I can't imagine 250 variables vs a list, even if it was based on an enum of the 250 things... At least you could walk through the list respectively.  Maybe you needed to have your first argument as a string to show their "iA", "iB", "iC" labels.

Comment: @DRapp Thank you. I think you are very right. I also have the feeling that the OP is not understanding the true problem: wrong class design. A class with 250+ variables/properties is indeed very "uncommon" and for sure an indicator for bad design.

Comment: Maybe a tweak in your code to show an example enumeration of their IA - IF design, doing a loop to populate and setting that list as the binding might open their eyes.  Then notify them of your adjustments to the answer.  They definitely dont get design at this level, they will fall far behind moving forward.  Like your effort and clarity in notes too.

Comment: @CoderGreat Honestly, I think you are totally on the wrong track. This is not how object oriented programming works. Your class must reflect the entity it is representing, which is in your case a row with two columns or in other terms an object with two attributes. A class with 250 attributes can never be right. I have updated my answer to show how to create the table from your image. Please also read my answer to your previous comment, which I've added as part of my answer. Please let me know if you need help to refactor your code.

Comment: @ IA is not string value is a int property of My class . user enter the value in grid column that value bind to IA property. IA,IB,IC,ID,IE,IF,IG.....this is int property

Comment: You can make the property type according to your needs. I just followed your posted image, which clearly showed a string value e.g. "IA" in the first column. In general, the data type or number of columns is irrelevant. It's about the concept. You were approaching the problem to show a table wrong. You can modify the example to match your requirements. The example works for int, double, string, any type. Each item is a row. Each property of the item a column.

Comment: I expanded on your original sample to include the enums and dynamically building out the list for presentation of multiple rows.  Just FYI

Comment: @DRapp I think this is not what he wants. He said both columns are integers. To use an enum and the Description attribute to store data is not the best decision. The data his hidden as internal meta info. You need reflection to extract this information. I would prefer a collection of key value pairs or tuples or a dictionary. Only works comfortable for a pair of data. You also don't know if the data is constant. Too much assumptions due to lack of information. That's why I decided to only show how to create a table that looks like the posted image. Or I simply misunderstood the question.

Comment: @BionicCode, the enum is a number, no problem, the description could be shown for it's context.  I agree with you on alternatives, but even better would probably be a database with records to query from too.  I was just trying to show context of looping construct with structure similar to what you offered.  However, as a structure (like yours), you could expand upon it with many other properties and show under different columns within a grid display.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do does not make a whole lot of sense, especially from a maintenance perspective.  You have apparently 250 variables that you want to list.  What if this list ever gets cut short, or extends, and you now have 2389 variables (exaggerated, but just for the point).  You would be pulling your hair out trying to maintain it.

Instead, you should learn more about class structures, more probable databases too and trying to find a common pattern.  Each "thing" you have is an integer-based item.  But each "thing" has a corresponding purpose, or description such as your IA, IB, IC, etc.

I am proposing you CONSIDER the following.  I have made an enumerator with a list of things.  Example below, but I only have items for IA-IG.  I also, for sample purposes, put a description associated with two of these things.

```
public enum my250Things
{
    IA,
    IB,
    [Description("this is item C")]
    IC,
    ID,
    IE,
    [Description("testing F description")]
    IF,
    IG
}
```

So, now in your code, if I have a variable based on the type of "my250Things", I can refer to it by its enum to know what it represents.

Back to your data grid.  Since all your records to be presented are one row each, and showing the corresponding variable name context (IA, IB, etc) and the value it contains, I created a class.  This class actually has 3 properties.  A show value, a show int, and the original enum value it was created based on.  Below.

```
public class YourCommonThings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _yourShowValue;
    public string YourShowValue
    {
        get { return _yourShowValue; }
        set { _yourShowValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int _yourIntValue;
    public int YourIntValue
    {
        get { return _yourIntValue; }
        set
        {
            _yourIntValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private my250Things _theOriginalEnum;
    public my250Things TheOriginalEnum
    {
        get { return _theOriginalEnum; }
        set
        {
            _theOriginalEnum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now, I want to populate a list of things I want to present to the user.  Since the enum lets me know the "things" I am trying to track, I can use it to populate the list, along with it's description(s) where applicable.  If none, it defaults with the string representation of the enum itself.  I created a simple window "Stack1" for a demo, created a public property for binding the data list to and auto-populate based on the enum.

You will need these "using" references at the top of the window's  .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
```

Here is the code within the window's code-behind

```
public partial class Stack1 : Window
{

    // first, making a public property as a list of the things I want to present
    public List<YourCommonThings> BindToThisListOfThings { get; set; }

    // the name of my window is called "Stack1" and this is the constructor of the window
    public Stack1()
    {

        // start by declaring a new list of things based on the class
        BindToThisListOfThings = new List<YourCommonThings>();

        // Now, we can dynamically create a list of all the "things" you are trying to present
        // into your data grid.  In this case, I am going through an enumerator list, but could
        // also be done if the list of things was stored in a database (for example) and you 
        // queried from that, but that is a different question / option.
        foreach(my250Things oneThing in  typeof( my250Things ).GetEnumValues() )
        {
            // creating one instance of whatever your enum underlying thing is and
            // default setting the properties within the class instance for the parts
            // that are within the { }
            // the ".ToString()" portion will get your "IA","IB", ...
            // I can also add in to store the original enum value while I'm at it,
            // even though not showing to the end user in the screen.
            var justOne = new YourCommonThings
                    {   YourShowValue = oneThing.ToString(),
                        YourIntValue = 0,
                        TheOriginalEnum = oneThing };

            // and you can optionally just for sake of example purposes associate a description
            // to an enum value and pull THAT instead...
            string description = GetEnumDescription(oneThing);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
                justOne.YourShowValue = description;

            // Now, add to your list
            BindToThisListOfThings.Add(justOne);
        }

        // Now, you have your list prepared and ready to go for binding to
        DataContext = this;

        // and finish initializing the rest of the form.
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // this static method is used to get the "description" component
    // out of the enumeration declaration IF such a description is declared.
    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Any())
            return attributes.First().Description;

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Finally, in the xaml of the form, I have the binding of the data grid to the list of things prepared from the enum.

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding BindToThisListOfThings, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Name" Binding="{Binding YourShowValue}" Width="125" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Argument Value" Binding="{Binding YourIntValue}" Width="125" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Now, within the form/window, or wherever you have your MVVM pattern defined (doubt at this point), but anyhow, however you plan on saving data, you can just cycle through the list of things, and get its respective thing and description to save wherever you plan, but that was not disclosed in your question to apply further.

```
public void SaveData()
{
    foreach( var oneThing in BindToThisListOfThings )
    {
        // Here, you can refer to 
        // oneThing.YourShowValue
        // oneThing.YourIntValue
        // oneThing.TheOriginalEnum
    }
}
```

Good luck.